# Does typeof evaluate to "Function" (capital initial) in any JS implementation?

Tags: javascript

I might have seen `typeof value === "function" || typeof value === "Function"` in an answer for a function test on this website. I want to know if my memory is correct and that this is necessary for a more widely-compatible test for functions.

Comment: Technically, it's an implementation of ECMAScript, of which JavaScript is one. [The ECMAScript standard lists all of the possible return values for the `typeof` operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-typeof-operator-results). All of them are lower case.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A programming language is not an implementation.

Comment: Then what do *you* mean by a "JS implementation"?

Answer (score 3):

Your memory is not totally correct, you can test for `typeof value === "function"` or `value instanceof Function`, not `typeof value === "Function"`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

The [ECMAScript specification for `typeof`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-typeof-operator) defines the results as the following:

> | Type of val | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | Undefined | **"undefined"** |
> | Null | **"object"** |
> | Boolean | **"boolean"** |
> | Number | **"number"** |
> | String | **"string"** |
> | Symbol | **"symbol"** |
> | BigInt | **"bigint"** |
> | Object (does not implement [[Call]]) | **"object"** |
> | Object (implements [[Call]]) | **"function"** |

So any function (object with a [[[Call]] internal method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-essential-internal-methods-of-function-objects)) will return the string `"function"` all lowercase.

Comment: Everyone gets that, but sometimes there are deviations, like `RegExp` objects being callable in Chrome.

Comment: That's for stuff that is *not* part of the spec. If you have an environment where `typeof fn` returns `"Function"` with an uppercase, then *it is not ECMAScript compliant*. Therefore what you are running is not JavaScript. It's some other language. Also, I don't see regex objects being callable in Chrome. The `RegExp` *constructor* is but I don't find that surprising or odd.